# How to fix 'characters' is unavailable: Please use String directly in swift 5

Tags: swift

i've some code to filtering number inside variable.

Here's the code:

```
var numbers = String(anotherNumbers.characters.filter { "01234567890.".characters.contains($0) })
```

In the swift 3, this code working correctly. But in the Swift 5, i get an error `'characters' is unavailable: Please use String directly`

How to fix this error?
Thankyou.

Comment: Just delete the word “characters” (and a dot).

Comment: `let numbers = anotherNumbers.filter("01234567890.".contains)`

Comment: remove ".characters" only.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can remove characters to use String directly.

For example

```
var anotherNumbers = "0123456789"
var numbers = String(anotherNumbers.filter { "01234567890.".contains($0) })
```

returns "0123456789"

Comment: Initializing a new String object trom the result here is pointless. Btw no need to pass a closure to the filter method